# If/else with test on checkbox in SELENIUM IDE

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to do an if/else test in SELENIUM IDE. If the checkbox is checked the test should run the IF-condition, whereas otherwise it should go into the ELSE. I tried several commands for the TARGET of the IF, but each time it chose the same way regardless of whether the condition pertained or not. So I need to know how to deal with the notation of SELENIUM IDE in this case. Hope anybody can help me by showing me how I can make the condition dependent on a checkbox..

Comment: Consider sharing your code, we'd be much more helpful then. Till then, [read this official Selenium IDE documentation on conditional testing](https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow).

Comment: COuld you accept the answer

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**A simple if statement works like given above, you could try yourself.**

If you change the target value to `true` for *`if command`* then the output will be `Passed` and if you keep it as `false`, the output will be `fail`.

**Coming to your question**

if you want to verify whether a checkbox is selected. You can use the `verify checked` command.

But, these commands do not have any return value and so, cannot be used for conditional statements.

For controlling the flow according to checkbox status, you can use execute script command to verify the 'checked' property of the element:

**Add the below command in IDE:**

```
command: execute script
Target : return (document.querySelectorAll('[name="selected(1234)"]'))[0].checked
value: test
```

**Note:** queryselector is the function to identify an element using CSS locator, full list of supported element locators  could be found at :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Note that few locators return arrays and few returns single element. You should handle it accordingly. for instance, query selector returns an array of 1 element so I took [0] the first element.

**Final code would look like:**

[image]

**.side file:**

Just copy the below code and save it as `test.side` file. Now open it in IDE and run it and see how the control flow works.

```
{
  "id": "e775f634-710f-41a4-9d86-ed26d93f5f78",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "sdad",
  "url": "http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "81f96aae-1436-4766-9005-f868d5350de4",
    "name": "sd",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "50ff0f41-4ec0-41fa-992f-d2ec9d4f6381",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/chapter1",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "a8a9e9b1-1d61-49a3-ab18-5e6598e5c1ed",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "setWindowSize",
      "target": "1897x1040",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "408fc4ff-6bbd-4c42-b8d3-f09ca43a5b45",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "select",
      "target": "id=selecttype",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "label=Selenium Core"
    }, {
      "id": "163049da-7205-440d-923c-51356cc5f22b",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "//click",
      "target": "name=selected(1234)",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f6f8739c-86c6-40ea-a235-eeb8c7c2f374",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "executeScript",
      "target": "return (document.querySelectorAll('[name=\"selected(1234)\"]'))[0].checked",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "test"
    }, {
      "id": "d7952432-7499-4173-b7bd-e09663163708",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "${test}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "0e83238a-ec38-4247-b1e6-485bd81c680a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "if",
      "target": "${test}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "6f832f5c-31df-41f1-a399-c7348095f614",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "Passed",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "6d2f22db-11b5-43b8-a56e-1ef7991fd503",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "else",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "c77edb7b-22df-4507-91bc-f03c7e71bddb",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "fail",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "30c78100-ab95-4382-8ae2-b98ee8d60826",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "end",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "cb4118db-162f-4ca5-a002-ceb87733dbba",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["81f96aae-1436-4766-9005-f868d5350de4"]
  }],
  "urls": ["http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

**Final code looks like:**

[image]

Now you can see how test flow changes by running the test with step 4 enabled and then disabled

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer!

Comment: @elerius could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: And, if you needed to say NOT checked, just put a `!` in front: `!document.querySelector`

Comment: Also we can skip the `echo` and `execute script` stuff and just use the conditional expression directly inside as the _target_ of the `if`.