# If/Else with Selenium IDE - when confirmation message comes up

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a scenario, in case of the user registration successful, it will display a success message on the next page otherwise an error message shows on the same page.
How to automate the test case to return as passed if it is success and failure in case of error message comes up.

Please help me out here.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If/else with test on checkbox in SELENIUM IDE](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42303/if-else-with-test-on-checkbox-in-selenium-ide)

Comment: Retracted close vote as the answer doesn't enitrely solve the question

Answer (score 2):

There is no return value for verify element, so as a work around  use, "Store xpath count" . If 0, it means no element, if 1 it means element present.

[image]

The below answer gives more complecated if/else scenarios:

[If/else with test on checkbox in SELENIUM IDE](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42303/if-else-with-test-on-checkbox-in-selenium-ide)